# Ember errors "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'typeKey' of undefined " on model save

Tags: ember.js

My RESTAdapter config:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend
  namespace: '/api'
```

My model:

```
module.exports = App.Cat = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr 'string'
  description: DS.attr 'string'
  picture: DS.attr 'string'
  location: DS.attr 'string'
  profileStyle: DS.attr 'string'
  created: DS.attr 'date'
```

My route:

```
Cat = require '../../models/cat'

App.CatNewRoute = Em.Route.extend
  model: ->
    @store.createRecord(Cat, {
      created: new Date()
    })
```

My controller:

```
App.CatNewController = Em.ObjectController.extend
  actions:
    addCat: ->
      console.log 'saving...'
      @get('model').save().then ->
        console.log 'all done'
```

I've verified with the Ember inspector that my model has all the attributes that get assigned through a form on the template at the time of save (except for an id which is null - I think this is normal and Ember by default uses the ID assigned to a model by the server). Whenever I  save the model I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'typeKey' of undefined
```

This error occurs here in the ember data source code:

```
if (container) {
  adapter = container.lookup('adapter:' + type.typeKey) || container.lookup('adapter:application');
}
```

I'm using Ember-data 1.0.0 beta 3-2 and Ember 1.0.0-4. I've tried a few different versions of Ember data to the same effect.

Close approximation in jsBin: http://jsbin.com/ixIqIjI/6/edit?html,js,console,output

This jsBin also errors with the typeKey error.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution. `createRecord` takes `type` and `record` arguments, but the `type` can not be the explicit Model name like `App.Cat`, it has to be a string which Ember then attaches to the correct model based on the name. In this case, the correct way to create the record is `this.store.createRecord('cat', {...} )`

Answer (score 0):

I think that your require is returning undefined.

```
Cat = require '../../models/cat'
Cat // the variable Cat is undefined
```

So, this code will fail

```
@store.createRecord(Cat /* Cat is undefined*/, {
  created: new Date()
})
```

Are you sure that the cat model is in the path `../../models/cat` ?

Some build tools like [ember-tools](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-tools),  need that you expose the class using `module.exports`, if you are using it, you need to use:

```
module.exports = Cat;
```

in your cat.js file.

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Marcio! My require for Cat is indeed returning the model. I have `module.exports = App.Cat = DS.Model.extend` in my actual file, I left it off to make it easier to read for the purposes of StackOverflow.


I checked to be sure by placing a debugger in the route and checking the value of Cat after requiring it and it points to `App.Cat`.

I've edited my original question in case anybody else thinks the same thing you do.

Comment: You are welcome. This is strange, because the only way to receive this error is if `Cat` is undefined. In the runtime `type.typeKey` will become `Cat.typeKey` and the value of typeKey is "cat". I have tried to simulate this problem without success. Can you simulate this in a fiddle?

Comment: This is a close approximation that errors in a different way (cannot save null): http://jsbin.com/ixIqIjI/1/edit

Comment: I updated to use the FixtureAdapter, but in my case worked. The console prints `all done`, please give a look http://jsbin.com/ixIqIjI/2/edit. I still think that you are receiving this error because your build tool. This is a jsbin where I force your current error http://jsbin.com/ixIqIjI/5/edit

Comment: Can you post an example of it working with the RESTAdapter? I can get it working with Fixtures too, but I want this hooked up with a server, not just using static data. Thanks!
Obviously it'll still error out because there won't be a server with the Fiddle, but it should still progress past where it is currently, right?

Also, with your example of you "forcing" the error, it actually errors before my example. In yours, it sees that the route is creating a bad record and won't even progress to render the `cat.new` template whereas mine gets that far and simply fails at the execution of `addCat`

Answer (score 0):

I updated your JSBin to work.
You have to pass the string version of the model, so for App.Cat you would pass "cat" for something like App.BigPost you would pass "bigPost" the string will be resolved to a model and then the ember-data adapter will know what to do.

Working version - http://jsbin.com/ixIqIjI/10/edit